# BindingResult object stay empty

Tags: spring, validation, thymeleaf

I can'figure out why my validation sample code doesn't work !
This is my object :

```
@PasswordMatches
public class UtilisateurInscriptionEnCoursDto implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -4445329534944784344L;

/** The id. */
private Long id;

@NotNull(message = "Saisissez votre nom")
@NotEmpty
private String nom;

@NotNull
@NotEmpty(message = "Saisissez votre prénom")
private String prenom;

@NotNull
@NotEmpty(message = "Entrez un mot de passe")
private String password;

private String matchingPassword;

@ValidEmail
@NotNull
@NotEmpty(message = "Saisissez votre adresse mail")
private String email;
```

And this is my Controller :

```
   @GetMapping("/inscription")
public String afficherFormulaireInscription(WebRequest request, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("user", new UtilisateurInscriptionEnCoursDto());
    return "inscription";
}

@PostMapping("/inscription")
public String enregistrerCompteUtilisateur(@ModelAttribute("user") @Valid UtilisateurInscriptionEnCoursDto utilisateurInscriptionEnCoursDto,
        BindingResult result, Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "inscription";
    }

    try {
        this.gestionUtilisateuFacade.verifierEmailInscriptionUtilisateur(utilisateurInscriptionEnCoursDto);
    } catch (UtilisateurExistantException ueEx) {
        String errMessage = this.messages.getMessage("message.regError", null, request.getLocale());
        model.addAttribute("message", errMessage);
        return "inscription";
    } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        LOGGER.warn("Impossible de s'inscrire", ex);
        return "inscription";
    }

    return "succesInscription";
}
```

The try/catch bloc works well, but I can't succeed having result.hasErrors() == true, even if I leave all fields blank.

Any idea to help

Thx a lot.

Comment: Hi. Are you using spring boot and if yes, which version? If you are using spring boot 2.3+ maybe you need dependency spring-boot-starter-validation.

Comment: You got it thx :)

Answer (score 2):

I added my comment as answer:

If you are using spring boot 2.3+ maybe you need dependency spring-boot-starter-validation.